# How to forbid entering of semicolon at end of any line of my vuejs app

Tags: vuejs2, eslint

In my  @vue/cli 4.0.5 app I use eslint with options in package.json :

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": "~4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.2.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.1.2",
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  }
```

and I want to forbid entering of semicolon at end of any line of my code.

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found useful options in  package.json:

```
"rules": {
    "semi": [2, "never"]
}
```

Which Raise errors when ";" at end of ,y code line and that salved my problem